# Prove that $\log(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{-t} - e^{-st}) t^{-1}dt$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that for $s$, with $\Re(s) > 1$, $\log(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{-t} - e^{-st}) t^{-1}dt$. I first rewrite the integral on the right hand side of the equation as $$\int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{-t} t^{-1} - e^{-st} t^{-1})\mathrm dt$$ which is equal to $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{-1} \mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} t^{-1}\mathrm dt$$ Then I found that the first term coincides with $\Gamma(0)$, which is undefined, since $0$ is a pole. Could anyone tell me what I should do to solve this problem? Thanks so much!

**EDIT** I used the hint given in the comment. Then I rewrite the integral as $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-1}e^{t} - e^{-s} e^{t}}{t} dt$. Then I have this is equal to $$(e^{\infty} - e^{0}) \ln\left(\frac{e^{-1}}{e^{-s}}\right)$$ which is equal to $$(e^{\infty} - e^{0}) \ln(e^{s-1})$$

 Then I get the integral is equal to $$(s-1) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{t}\mathrm dt$$

Comment: Hint: use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral).

Comment: @J.G. I used the hint you gave and updated my post

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you! I'll try your hint, too.

Comment: @Miranda: It is basically what the link by  J.G. does.

Comment: Your attempt to use my suggestion has malfunctioned. In terms of $f(t):=e^{-t}$, note $e^{-st}$ is $f(st)$, not $e^{-s}f(-t)$. You've similarly mishandled the other exponential.

Comment: By Fubini-Tonelli's: $$\int^\infty_0\int^{st}_{t}e^{-u}\,du\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^\infty_0\mathbb{1}_{\{t<u<st\}}\frac{1}{t}\,dt\Big)e^{-u}\,du=\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^{u}_{u/s}\frac{1}{t}\,dt\Big)e^{-u}\,du$$

Comment: Thank you guys for your hints! I posted my answer

Comment: A very easy proof follows by noting that the integral gives an analytic function of $s$ when $\Re s>0$ and you can differentiate under the integral sign with result being $1/s$; a simple check at $1$ gives the initial contact allows to deduce that $f(s)=\log s$ actually for all $\Re s>0$

Comment: In the case of your (analytical) integrand a simple integration by part perfectly works: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-st}}tdt=\ln t(e^{-t} - e^{-st})\bigg|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty\ln t\,e^{-t}dt-s\int_0^\infty\ln t\,e^{-st}dt$$
Both integrals converges. Making the substitution $x=st$ in the second
$$=\int_0^\infty\ln te^{-t}dt-\int_0^\infty\ln xe^{-x}dx+\ln s\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=\ln s$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's good to post an answer here, since I have solved this problem.
Since this integral is an Frullani integral, then we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-st}}{t} \mathrm dt = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{e^{n}} - \frac{1}{e^{0}}\right) \ln\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)$$ which is equal to $-\ln\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)$, which is just $\ln(s)$.